# My list of references just won't update after adding items in bibliography.bib file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, texworks

I am using TexWorks and I have created a report using references from a .bib file.

Now I have added more references in .bib but when I compile again the list of references in the report won't update.

I looked at :[Force TeXworks to refresh bib file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/force-texworks-to-refresh-bib-file)

I tried to delete .aux files ..

The compiler is

```
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

And the bib is added as :

```
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
```

But nothing seems to be working.

How to do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: latex never reads the bib file you need to run pdflatex then biber then pdflatex twice more

Comment: I have a book.tex in which I include the chapters in it. Do I have to do that process for each chapter as well (didn't work on book.tex only btw)?

Comment: The expression "force TeXworks to refresh the bib file" is quite misleading: TeXworks is an editor and a front end to various executable programs, including `biber`, but it does not do any "refreshing" of its own. What you need to do  while in TeXworks is to run `biber`. Have you located TeXworks's pull-down menu (likely located near the upper-left corner) that lets you select which external program to run; the default program is likely `pdflatex`? See how you can change the selection to run `biber` instead.

Comment: by default no although there are packages that offer per capter bibliographies. But first make sure you have asked texworks to run _biber_ the answer you link to is about running _bibtex_

Comment: i do run biber but still not working

Comment: Aside: which version of TeXworks are you running? (The most recent version if 0.6.9.)

Comment: After running biber, do you run pdflatex twice more?

Comment: "not working" is not a useful description if you want anyone to help. It will either work or it will give an error message. You have given no information at all about your input,what you ran, or what error you got

Comment: I get no error, simply the references section generated through  the command \printbibliography is not being updated with the new entries in .bib file

Comment: do you `\cite` the new entries? they will not appear (normally) just by adding them to the bib

Comment: Yes I cite them and they do not turn into numbers as they suppose to be after adding them to the bib, but rather keep as key names

Comment: i use \addtocategory with \DeclareBibliographyCategory then \printbibliography[heading=none,category=keyword]

Comment: Now they work but only if I use \cite in conjuction with printbibliography command not using only \printbibliography[heading=none,category=keyword] which I don't want (I want them to appear only using the latter command only)

Comment: never mind: I used \nocite in conjuction with \printbibliography[heading=none,category= to make them appear in my chapter ;)

Comment: It is always a good idea to post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the problem instead of adding more information in the comments.